# Significant rounding differences using pandas' to_numpy with different versions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, version-control, rounding

I found significant differences in my results while running the same script in two different Python environments, which I ultimately traced back to one of them using `pandas 0.25.3`, and the other its latest release (`1.3.2` at the time of writing).

Within the script itself, I isolated what I believe is the "culprit" as the `to_numpy` function. The main difference I could observe at this level was a change in rounding at the 10th decimal, and making the script round my DataFrames at the 9th decimal before hand largely solved the problem.

However, as I tried to compare the docs for `to_numpy` in both versions, I didn't see anything that could justify such a difference.

Is there anything I missed that could explain this ?

Comment: What are the datatypes in your table that are rounded when calling `to_numpy`?

Comment: @w-m Mostly `float64`, as well as a few `int64` that aren't involved in further calculations.

Comment: As float64 is supported in both Pandas and NumPy, there is no rounding involved in `to_numpy`. Maybe you are running into an issue with the float precision when printing or converting to string, at a later time? It's possible the default precision for printing differs between versions. Try to build a reproducible example with a single number and just a few lines of code that demonstrates the effect you're seeing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.